# Precautions taking the Tren a las Nubes

Tags: health, trains, argentina, altitude

I would really like to once ride with the [tren a las Nubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tren_a_las_Nubes). Wikipedia says the tour takes 15 hours, but I can't find any information on where to buy tickets and if reservation is necessary. And how much does it cost?

The highest point on the route is over 4200 meters. Do I need to take any special precautions because of this height? Normally if I go climbing in the Alps it is necessary to prepare when going above 4000 meters. But in this case, it is only a passive activity and most important only for a short period. I think you can only get really altitude sick after approximately 6 hours. So it shouldn't be a problem in this case?

Comment: For a moment I read this as "Tren a las Nudes", and all kinds of visual pictures flew through my mind.

Comment: I'm waiting for our nudism week to ask such questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [buy your tickets here](http://www.trenalasnubes.com.ar/turismo_salta/en_tren_a_las_nubes_reservas_online_tickets.html). The price is about 185 USD.

It's not necessary to do any special preparation, as the train will take you back to "normal" altitudes after a couple of hours at 4200m. When I was in Argentina, the train didn't work, so we had to rent a car to do more or less the same path the train makes. We stayed about 2 or 3 hours at 4000 meters and started feeling a bit bad, nothing important, but I believe if we had stayed some more time we could have had some problems. We had headache for the rest of the day and the night, so I recommend not to plan any hard activity for the next day when you go.

Answer (score 5):

Please, do be careful with the altitude; I've had some horror stories.

Generally it's considered that above 2400m things start getting interesting.  It's definitely worth acclimatising for a couple of days if you're  doing anything physical at that altitude.

However, as you point out, it's a passive activity for a short period of time.  Perhaps take some anti-altitude sickness pills or cocoa leaves beforehand, to help with any symptoms.

But as long as you're not over-stressing your body, and don't have anything too physical planned for the preceding or following day, you should be ok.